# Как прочитать файл с райширением .ebc (ebcdic) через python?

Tags: python-3.x, utf-8, unicode, decode, json-encode

Возникла такая проблема, есть файл в формате .ebc (ebcdic), его размер более 10 Гб. Не получается прочитать с помощью python. При попытке конвертировать через utf-8 и прочее, выдает ошибку.

Comment: Вызвать для перекодировки [iconv](https://linux.die.net/man/1/iconv)?

Answer (score 1):

ebcdic - это [специальный двоичный формат](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC).
Поэтому просто декодировать в строку не получится, стандартная реализация Python ничего не знает о таком формате сообщений.

Быстрое гугление подсказывает библиотеку https://pypi.org/project/ebcdic/, скорее всего, она должна помочь.